# CSS background repeating

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fix the background color / image should be limited within my div but its not working its expanding throughout the section

here is my html

```
<section id="portfolio">

        <div class="port">

        <h2>my Portfolio</h2>

<ul id="links">
    <li><a href="#" style="background-color: rgb(153, 150, 145);"><img src="assets/img/234.png" alt="my Image"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="background-color: #fff"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="background-color: #3D8D94"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="background-color:#383838;"><img src="assets/img/123.png" alt="image 2"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="background-color: #000" ></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="background-color:#090C0C"></a></li>
</ul>
        </div>

        </section>
```

my background should be behind H2 and list not above and below that.

Comment: Can you post your css? Just an inkling but have you set `background-repeat: no-repeat?

Comment: where do you set background to your div. I can't see

Answer (score 1):

Set your id/class `css` style to

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the H2 inside a div and add a background color to that div.

```
<div style="background-color: #F00;"><h2>my Portfolio</h2></div>
```

Something like this.